# How to integrate $xe^{3x} (\sin(2x))$?

Tags: integration

I dont know how to integrate $e^{3x} (\sin(2x))$.  Not even a vague idea. Can you help me, whether to use a substitution method or partial fraction method or divide throughout by some value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \text{Let} \ \ I=\int e^{3x} sin(2x) dx $$

Using integration by parts $$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} u=e^{3x} & v'=sin(2x)\\ u'=3e^{3x} & v=-\frac{1}{2}cos(2x) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\int uv' = uv - \int u'v$$

$$ I  = -\frac{3}{2}e^{3x}cos(2x) + \frac{3}{2}\int e^{3x}cos(2x)  $$
and one more time!

$$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} u=e^{3x} & v'=cos(2x)\\ u'=3e^{3x} & v=\frac{1}{2}sin(2x) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\color{blue}I= -\frac{3}{2}e^{3x}cos(2x)+ \frac{3}{2} \Big ( \frac{1}{2}e^{3x}sin(2x) - \color{blue}{ \frac{3}{2}I } \Big )$$

Can I leave you to solve for $I$ ? 
(Hopefully I haven't made any silly errors, but this method will definitely obtain the answer

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

Use Euler's formula to rewrite
$$ \sin 2x = \frac{e^{2xi}-e^{-2xi}}{2i} $$
and then simplify your integrand into
$$ \frac{e^{(3+2i)x}-e^{(3-2i)x}}{2i}$$
which can easily be integrated term for term.

Comment: I think this may be beyond the OP, as he is unfamilliar perhaps with integration by parts -- one step at a time!

Answer (score 0):

Apply integration by parts **twice**, but make the same choice of functions to integrate/differentiate (otherwise, you simply undo your first step with the second).

After integrating/differentiating twice, the functions $e^{3x}$ and $\sin(2x)$ return to the same form, up to scaling factors; you'll end up with something of the form:
$$\color{blue}{\int e^{3x}\sin(2x) \, \mbox{d} x} = (\cdots) + k \color{blue}{\int e^{3x}\sin(2x) \, \mbox{d} x}$$
and you can simply solve for the integral (in blue).

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the integral of $\mathrm e^{3x}\mathrm e^{2ix}=\mathrm e^{(3+2i)x}$:
$$\frac1{3+2i}\,\mathrm e^{(3+2i)x}=\frac{(3-2i)\mathrm e^{3x}\mathrm e^{2ix}}{5}$$
and retain the `imaginary part`:
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{3x}(3\sin 2x-2\cos 2x)}{5}$$
Note you also get $\displaystyle\int\mathrm e^{3x}\cos 2x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x\;$ as a bonus.